# During fork, how tx that was sent from full node is been mined on the two blockchains?

Tags: transactions, peers, hardforks

My full node connected to 0,...,n peers and follows the longest chain after Istanbul fork - the miner's chain.

General transaction flow: full-node get the tx, validates and broadcast to its peers.

If I understand right the only way it reaches the Istanbul fork chain is that a peer of my node will be connected to the Istanbul chain.

Is it possible to be a mixed peer, that has peers on Miner's chain and another peer on the Istanbul chain?